# Why PCA code is not running, the matrix is 0х0?

Tags: r, pca, factominer

```
df_scaled <- as.data.frame(scale(df))
features <- df_scaled[, -10]
target <- df_scaled[, 10]
pc <- PCA(features, graph = FALSE)
print(pc)

Error in eigen(crossprod(t(X), t(X)), symmetric = TRUE) :0х0 matrix
```

where is the error?

I have 19178 obs. of  29 variables, so it is strange that the program does not work

Comment: Hello Victoria, must share a sample of data for the problem to be reproducible. 
What `summary(features)` returns?

Comment: Hello, Ric!

age        height_cm     weight_kg      overall      potential  
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA   Median : NA   Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA 

(summary(features)) returns this

Comment: all your data is NA. Review your `df`. Perhaps all columns are text columns or similar